# CKFinder - Limit storage size

Tags: php, ckfinder

I'm using CKFinder 2.1, and I want to limit its total storage size.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think you forgot part of your

Comment: I think I got the gist of what he was asking in my edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum upload size can be adjusted for each resource type in its `configuration`

Change `'maxSize' => 0` to what ever you want it to be

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
'name' => 'Files', // Single quotes not allowed
'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
'maxSize' => 0,
'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,
ppt,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xml,zip',
'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
'name' => 'Images',
'url' => $baseUrl . 'images',
'directory' => $baseDir . 'images',
'maxSize' => 0,
'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
'name' => 'Flash',
'url' => $baseUrl . 'flash',
'directory' => $baseDir . 'flash',
'maxSize' => 0,
'allowedExtensions' => 'swf,flv',
'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is good but could you please tell me 'maxSize' calculation is in KB's (or) MB's?